# Horizontal scroll with vertical overflow in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have a navigation menu across the top of my page that shows menu items, and on hover shows sub-menu items, and allows for horizontal overflow with a scrollbar. The solution must not require JavaScript.

I can get the drop-downs working just fine if I don't have horizontal overflow.

[image]

I can get the horizontal working the way I want too.

[image]

But then I lose the vertical overflow so I can't see my drop downs at all.

The menu needs to be only the height of the initially-visible menu items and obviously in the example the button needs to be clickable.

I believe the issue is that setting `overflow-x` to `auto` creates a new block formatting context so `overflow-y` can't be `visible` and my overflow gets hidden.

Is there any way that I can have both horizontal scroll and vertical overflow?

```css
.menu-items--depth-0 {
  /* These three give me the horizontal scroll I want, but then the drop-downs don't show */
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;

  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.menu-items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-item--depth-0 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
}

.menu-items--depth-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 300ms;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-item--depth-0:hover .menu-items--depth-1 {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-0">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item one
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item two
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">Menu item three</li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item four
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button>Some clickable thing</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I know it ruins design, but removing `.menu-item--depth-0 {
  display: inline-block;
}` Makes them visible.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu-items--depth-0 {
  /* These three give me the horizontal scroll I want, but then the drop-downs don't show */
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;

  /** You do not require overflow-y **/
  /* For the sub menus to be displayed, you need to have some height to the element or create some div element below the ul element. So that you can see the sub menus over the div element. */
  
  height: 200px;

  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.menu-items {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-item--depth-0 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
}

.menu-items--depth-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 300ms;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu-item--depth-0:hover .menu-items--depth-1 {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-0">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item one
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item two
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">Menu item three</li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item four
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button>Some clickable thing</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort but this pushes the content below the menu down, so isn't a usable solution.

Comment: That was just an example, for actual use remove the height attribute from the style and it should work.

Comment: Can you remove overflow-x attribute, because it is making ul to constrain it's height.

Answer (score 0):

You could try as below, I have got this using `ul li` tags instead of using `classes` which has been assigned to `ul` and `li's` multiple times, head ul works as parent element over-here which has `width:300px` and that's why it has scrollbar at x-axis and other drop-down works fine as no need to add `position:relative` to parent tag over-here, hope this works.

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
  background:#ccc;
  width:300px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul > li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 30px;
  background: white;
}
ul > li > ul{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  white-space:initial;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:155px;
  display:none;
}
ul > li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
}
ul > li:nth-child(4) > ul{
  margin-left:-122px;
}
ul > li > ul > li{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-0">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item one
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item one - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item two
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item two - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">Menu item three</li>

    <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-0">
      Menu item four
      <ul class="menu-items menu-items--depth-1">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - one</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - two</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - three</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item--depth-1">Menu item four - four</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <button>Some clickable thing</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: This pushes the entire page down if a user hovers over a menu item. I want the drop down to cover the content below like in my first screenshot.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Okay, but now I have updated my codes, check that, hope it works.

Comment: Close, but this doesn't work if the menu is scrolled along a little bit. The drop down doesn't align with the item it's dropping down from.

Answer (score -3):

that would go beyond the menu of your container must set position: fixed
in other cases, the need to use the JS

Comment: I don't know what this means.